# Which datatypes to use with CoreData/SQL to minimize conversions

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, core-data

The folowing problem: 
I have a mobile User Interface that for examples lets the user enter values like Date,Name,Age,Height,Distance.
I want to store these values in a Core Database.
AS I want to be able to make calculations with these values it probably makes sense to use the appropiate values in CoreData
like

```
Date: NSDate
Name: String
Age: Int16
Height: Double
Distance: Double
```

Now I also want to store these data in a remote SQL Database and so far I always have used varchar(100) fields. 
Which now becomes a problem as I start to have to do a lot of really ugly conversions like

```
let entry =  CoreDataObjectFromSQLNetwork()
let entry.age = NSNumber(integer: (dictionary["age"] as! String).toInt()!)
let entry.height = NSNumber(double: (dictionary["height"] as! String).toDouble()!)
```

So what is the best way or which types would you use dealing with Swift/CoreData/MySQL and you need like the typical types (String, Date, Integer, Double, Boolean)

Answer (score 0):

The *best* way is to use appropriate data types on both sides instead of just treating every possible data type as if it were a 100 character string. If that's not an option then you'll have to convert at some point.

If possible, the second-best way is to have your server API make appropriate conversions to/from `varchar` so that it actually provides numeric types to mobile clients. Your server will have a lot more CPU and electrical power than people's phones, so do the conversion there. Then just use the appropriate data types on the phones.

If that's not possible, well, you've kind of outlined your remaining option. You might be able to optimize things based on your projections of how much data there will be vs. how often you want to do numeric calculations on that data. You could convert all data to numeric types as soon as you receive it (which is what you describe). Or you could leave everything as strings and convert to numeric types only when you need to do a calculation. Which is best depends on your app. I'd prefer the former, but if there's **lots** of data and comparatively few calculations, that might not be best.

Comment: My Server returns a JSON Dictionary. IMHO thats always string-values. There is no way I can get real datatypes from the server or is there?

Comment: Depends on the server and whether you're in a position to change how it works. JSON supports numeric values, whether you can get the server to deliver them correctly is a different question.